# Maven Project URL

Tags: maven, url, netbeans, glassfish

I have made a EAR project with Maven in NeatBeans IDE running on Glassfish, and a problem with default URL of the project, instead of loading:

http://localhost:8080/Opine-war

is loading

http://localhost:8080/Opine-war-1.0-SNAPSHOT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-application PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Java EE Application 6.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-application_6_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-application>
</glassfish-application>
```

This is my pom.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
    <artifactId>Opine</artifactId>
    <groupId>br.edu.infnet</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

    <groupId>br.edu.infnet</groupId>
    <artifactId>Opine-ear</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>ear</packaging>

    <name>Opine-ear</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
                <configuration>
                    <version>6</version>
                    <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>br.edu.infnet</groupId>
            <artifactId>Opine-ejb</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>ejb</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>br.edu.infnet</groupId>
            <artifactId>Opine-war</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two options. One is to change the finalName inside the pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
```

above shows the default.

Another option is to change the context name of your application which is currently derived from the ear file name. But the deployed ear does not need to match the context name (which you want to be "Opine-war"?

You can customize this within the ear plugin (which is enabled if you use `<packaging>ear</packaging>`: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/examples/customizing-context-root.html